# Magento 2: Get names of all people who ordered the product

Tags: magento2, product, orders, event-observer

Our client would like to have names of all people who ordered a product included into the Out of Stock notification email. I seem to have issue with getting such info ...

Code I have to get the orders by product sku is (in helper):
($orderFactory is \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory)

```
public function getOrdersWithProductSku($productSku)
    {
        try {
            if ($productSku)
            {
                $orderCollection = $this->orderFactory->create();
                $tableName   = $this->orderFactory->getTableName('sales_order_item');
                $orderCollection->addFieldToSelect('*');
                $orderCollection->getSelect()
                ->join(
                    $tableName,
                    'main_table.entity_id = ' . $tableName. '.order_id'
                )->where('sku LIKE '.$productSku);

            $orderCollection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');

            return $orderCollection;
            }
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            return [];
        }
    }
```

Then parsing that collection in the Observer as:

```
try
                        {
                            $orderCollection = $this->helperData->getOrdersWithProductSku($productSku);
                            if ($orderCollection && !empty($orderCollection))
                            {
                                foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
                                    array_push($names, $order->getBillingAddress()->getName());
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                array_push($names, "Customer names list is either null or empty");
                            }
                        }
                        catch(\Exception $e)
                        {
                            array_push($names, "Error generating customer names: ". $e->getMessage());
                        }
```

Is there an easy way to do this .... simply get an array of names who ordered the product based on SKU

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by simply querying the database directly for such info